# Typedoc: how to document an application composed by client and server

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I want to document an application composed by a client and a server (each of them in its subdirectory with its `tsconfig.json`). At the top level I have a `tsconfig.json` containing the `references` section pointing to the two parts.

If I generate the documentation for each part separately everything works perfectly. For example for the client:

```
npx typedoc \
--out "doc/client" \
--tsconfig ./client `ls client/*.ts | grep -vF .d.ts`
```

But I want to generate the documentation for the whole application, is it possible? Using `doxygen` for C++ was possible. Also pointing to the root tsconfig does not work. Related to this, why should I list all the sources with this ls+grep kludge? Aren't they already listed inside tsconfig include section? If I remove them typedoc complains that no entry point is provided.
Thanks for clarifying!
mario

Comment: typescript 4.3.5, node 16.6.0, typedoc 0.21.5, npm 7.20.5 on Windows 10 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you reply with the technology stack you are using.